# why do I get Error: ENOENT open error when trying to render a doT.js view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dot.js, express-4

I am trying out doT.js for the first time and have written a very basic server setup:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var doT = require('express-dot');

var pub = __dirname+'/public';
var vws = __dirname+'/views';

app.set('views', vws);
app.set('view engine', 'dot');
app.engine('html', doT.__express);

app.use('/css',express.static(pub + '/css'));
app.use('/img',express.static(pub + '/imgs'));
app.use('/js',express.static(pub + '/js'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render(vws + '/index.html', { title: 'dynamic title' });
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('Server running on port 8080');
```

When I run the server and goto myaddress:8080 I get the following error:
    Error: ENOENT, open '/home/myproject/views/layout.html'

If I try calling index.html with res.sendFile it works (although of course I can't pass variables that way)

```
res.sendFile(vws + '/index.html')
```

Where am I going wrong? 
Why am i getting an error which seems to relate to a failed attempt at opening "layout.html" when no example I have seen mentions such a file?

I need to use res.render in order to pass variables to the template, but all the examples I have found do it the same way I tried in my first attempt.

Comment: i don't think dot has an express module, unless it was added recently?

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis Looks like you are right for express 4.  Checked the npm package data for express-dot and it does say 3.x.  Thats a shame, I was planning on using doT for the speed.  Without the express module, what is the best way to use it? Or is there an alternative engine that is comparable is speed?

Comment: you can use Jade or Ejs, that should work fine.

Comment: @NarendraSoni  I am not sure about Ejs, but I know that Jade is significantly slower the doT.js which is why I first chose it.

Comment: ect looks interesting, especially as they include a very impressive benchmark comparrison table http://ectjs.com/#benchmark, anyone used it?

Comment: I like using swig. It isn't the fastest but its quite fully featured.

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis Swig isn't the fastest bet its quite a lot faster then Jade and the feature list looks good, I will give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dot.js isn't yet integrated with express 4.0's view engine middleware hook.

[Swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/) is a similar application that is. It isn't quite as fast as dot.js, but for me it has a great balance of speed and features with an extremely intuitive syntax.

Full disclosure: I like swig.